# Preventing Eclipse from opening external program inside Eclipse editor

Tags: eclipse

I have an Excel file in the directory of my Eclipse project. When I double-click that file in the Package Explorer, Eclipse opens an instance of Excel as a new tab inside its editor window to the right.

Unfortunately this seems to be quite a buggy setup if there is another instance of Excel open outside of Eclipse:

- I can't bring the other instance into the foreground and thus I can't use it any more
- Excel lost a bunch of changes that I saved inside the editor window in Eclipse

So, I would really like to prevent Eclipse from opening Excel- (and possibly other) files inside a tab of the Eclipse editor. They should always open in a separate program (just as if I had opened the file from Windows Explorer). Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Window >> Preferences >> General >> Editors >> File Associations, click 'Add' right to the File Types list, add `.xls`, OK.

Now select .xls from the list, click 'Add' right to the Associated editors list, select External Programs Check Box, select Microsoft Excel, OK.

Comment: Sweet! That works. As a note: There are several "Microsoft Office Excel..." options. I chose "Microsoft Office Excel 97-2003 Worksheet" for *.xls and "Microsoft Office Excel Worksheet" for *.xlsx.

Comment: You might also have to close all open editors in eclipse, for the change to take effect.

Answer (score 2):

You can tell Eclipse to open Word, Excel, PDF etc. with the default external Editor in general, without adding *.doc, *.docx, *.xls, *.xlsx etc. to the File Associations:

Window => Preferences => General => Editors
Uncheck "Allow in-plcae system editors"

Source: "Prevent in-place OLE editors" of [Eclipse Tips and Tricks](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tips/platform_tips.html)

Comment: Finally, this is the neat and simple solution I've been missing, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Right click on Excel file -> Open With -> System editor

After the first time, Eclipse will remember that that Excel file needs to be opened with the system editor.

Comment: Unfortunately it only remembers to open that specific file in the system editor, but not **all** Excel files...